# The webcam is recognized by Windows 8, but no application can use it

Tags: windows-8, webcam

I have a webcam without signed drivers (that kind of cheap/old webcam that's not plug and play and requires a driver, otherwise it shows in device manager as a yellow question mark)

After I installed the drivers in Windows 8 x86 (drivers unsigned, got the "red confirmation" during the install), I see it in the device manager as a webcam, and I see it in the Metro control panel in the "devices" tab as a webcam.

But, no Metro application can see it and use it, from the preinstalled Camera app, to Skype.

I checked the authorization in the charms bar, and I gave them the permission to access camera/mic, but it doesn't work.

So, I have the feeling that you need a webcam with signed drivers for use with Metro/Modern UI applications, am I right?

Is there is a fix for this, or do I need to buy a new webcam?

Comment: Tried with admin privileges?

Comment: You can't run Modern UI applications with admin privileges, I think

Comment: Right. I totally forgot.

Comment: What system are the drivers for exactly?  Most x86 drivers are not signed, as Microsoft doesn't require them to be, most drivers are not signed unless they are required to be ( i.e. 64-bit drivers ).

Comment: The drivers are for XP/Vista x86. (The webcam is from year 2004, so I think the drivers are for XP)

Comment: Maybe check out this page: http://pureinfotech.com/2012/09/05/installing-unsigned-drivers-in-windows-8-step-by-step/ Not sure if it is relevant for your case, as you have been able to install the driver.

Comment: Can you give us a screenshot of the Webcam in Device Manager. Thanks.

Comment: It works with "classic" Windows apps (i.e. VLC) http://imgur.com/9SW8N

Comment: I installed skype for desktop and it works. It doesn't with Modern-ui Skype

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It need signed drivers to work in Modern UI Apps. I bought a Microsoft Lifecam Cinema and it works...

Answer (score 0):

Double-check that your Web cam drivers are up to date. Open Device Manager (Go to the Start screen and begin typing `Device Manager`), and attempt to update the corresponding drivers.

If you're using Boot Camp, boot into Mac, copy the Boot Camp drivers onto an external device such as a USB drive, boot into Windows, and rerun Boot Camp driver installation.